# How can I clear h:messages in an ace:dialog after an ajax event?

Tags: ajax, forms, validation, jsf, icefaces

I have a button (Make Popup Visible) which makes a pop-up visible.  When the form is submitted (Submit The Form), an error message can sometimes appear in the h:messages field, which is expected.

My problem is that, when I close the pop-up (Make Popup Invisible) and then re-open it (Make Popup Visible) the h:messages field is still populated with the old error message.

Is there a way I can clear the messages when the (Make Popup Visible) is pushed?  I don't want to do a full page submit to do this.

Button visibility:

```
<h:form id="mainForm">
    <h:commandButton value="Make Popup Visible"> 
        <f:ajax listener="#{controller.prepareDelete(item)}" render=":deleteItemPopup"/>
    </h:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

Pop-up:

```
<ace:dialog id="deleteItemPopup" visible="#{controller.deleting}">
    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{controller.deleting}" layout="block">
        <h:messages for="deleteItemPopupForm"/>
        <h:form id="deleteItemPopupForm">                                

            <ui:insert name="content">
                This contains a form which, when submitted, can cause
                an error message to be created and populate the h:messages
                field
            </ui:insert>

            <h:commandButton value="Submit The Form" action="#{controller.delete}"/>
            <h:commandButton value="Make Popup Invisible">
                <f:ajax listener="#{controller.cancel}" render=":deleteItemPopup"/>
            </h:commandButton>

        </h:form>
    </h:panelGroup>
</ace:dialog>
```

Commands:

```
public void prepareDelete(Item item) {
    deleting = true;
}

public void cancel() {
    deleting = false;
}

public void delete() {
    .
    .
    .
    } catch (MyException ex) {
        FacesUtils.sendMessage("deleteItemPopupForm", ex);
    }
```

}

Comment: Witha little jquery or plain javascript, you can easily remove the content on ghe dialog close event

Comment: Yeah, but I'd much prefer doing it the "JSF way"...even if it involved managing things in a backing bean with FacesContext or something.

Comment: This is a valid jsf way… the ace components do lots of jquery manipulation behind the scenes. A jsf way would be: on the dialog close event, do a remote call to the server (e.g. with the [omnifaces commandScript] (http://snapshot.omnifaces.org/components/commandScript) and in that command update the panel or messages.  But this,requires a server roundtrip

Comment: By "JSF way" I mean setting a render attribute or param or something somewhere :)  Something elegant.  If I were to do what you are talking about, couldn't I use controller.prepareDelete(item) somehow?  It's already making a trip to the server...

Comment: Sure, then just do an update of the messages component in that action

Comment: Well, I tried doing it manually but FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getMessageList("deleteItemPopupForm") shows as empty.  When I create the error, is shows that its in there but when I click the controller.prepareDelete(item) function and step through it it shows as empty.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71711/discussion-between-kukeltje-and-wsaxton).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like ICEfaces does some special stuff with messages:

http://www.icesoft.org/JForum/posts/list/19753.page#71521

I added this to my web.xml file and the messages now go away:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.icefaces.messagePersistence</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
```